# Проблема неблокирующего ввода с asyncio в Python 3

Tags: python, asyncio, coroutine

Всем привет! Знакомлюсь с асинхронным программированием и у меня возникла проблема, которую пока никак не могу решить.
Задача: код запрашивает и выводит текущий курс валют каждые 5 секунд. При этом есть параллельная функция: вводится текст с помощью клавиатуры и выводится в консоль в верхнем регистре. Функция с вводом текста повторяется сразу, как только заканчивается вывод. 
Открыла для себя библиотеку asyncio. Но теперь не знаю как реализовать в нем неблокирующий ввод с клавиатуры.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time
import asyncio


async def repeat():
    while True:
        data = urllib.request.urlopen('http://resources.finance.ua/ru/public/currency-cash.json')
        ParsedData = json.loads(data.read())
        print(ParsedData["organizations"][0]["currencies"]["EUR"])
        print(ParsedData["organizations"][0]["currencies"]["USD"])
        await asyncio.sleep(5.0)


#Здесь должна быть функция неблокирующего ввода    
#async def writeConsole():
      #while True:
       #inp = input()
       #print(str(inp).upper())
       #break


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
        loop.create_task(repeat())
        #loop.create_task(writeConsole())
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close
```

В итоге у меня не выходит найти решение того, как реализовать ввод с помощью этого модуля. Возможно у вас есть идеи? Или есть какая-то другая библиотека на Питоне?